# Messagebox modifications phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Can we make animations on the transition of MessageBox and change its default style or its look of displaying message,please help me am a newbie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a customized MessageBox, then Use MessagePrompt instead of MessageBox.

To download : [Code2Fun tools](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com)

For documentation: [MessagePrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt&referringTitle=Documentation)